# Override Datatable pdf button fnClick doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

The problem is that I want to dynamically change export file name.
To do so, I've overriden the fnClick function like the following :

```
{
                            "sExtends": "pdf",
                            "bSelectedOnly": true,
                            "mColumns": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                            "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                            "sTitle": 'Liste classes'
                                      + new Date().asString("ddmmyyyy à hhhmin"),
                            "fnComplete": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash, sFlash ) {
                                deselectVisibleNodes();
                            },
                            "fnClick":  function( nButton, oConfig, flash ) {
                                var title = getExportFileName();
                                var exportFileName = title + ".pdf";
                                flash.setFileName( getExportFileName()+".pdf" );
                                console.log(this.fnGetTitle(oConfig));
                                this.fnSetText( flash,
                                        "title:"+ title +"\n"+
                                        "message:"+ oConfig.sPdfMessage +"\n"+
                                        "colWidth:"+ this.fnCalcColRatios(oConfig) +"\n"+
                                        "orientation:"+ oConfig.sPdfOrientation +"\n"+
                                        "size:"+ oConfig.sPdfSize +"\n"+
                                        "--/TableToolsOpts--\n" +
                                        this.fnGetTableData(oConfig)
                                    );
                            }
                        }
```

I've added console log to show the result of this.fnGetTableData(oConfig) which contains my data.
The blocking issue is that the export file window (to save the file) is not displayed.
What's happening please ?

Comment: The above source is quoted up, full of unclosed "".

Comment: Well, when I edited the code i've deleted the quote by error. The export is working with what I put in the code above. The question is why am I not able to just use this.fnSetText( flash,  this.fnGetTableData(oConfig)); which doesn't work by way...? I've remarked I have to use the options....